# Android: ShapeDrawable on ImageButton: pixelated

Tags: android

I'm trying to display an icon inside of an ImageButton. The icon is given as a path. Now, the problem is the path appearing pixelated.
Any ideas where I can enable anti-aliasing for the ImageButton or for the ShapeDrawable? Or am I doing something wrong?

```
Path path = new Path();
path.moveTo(0f, 192f); path.lineTo(115, 365); path.cubicTo(123, 377, 135, 384, 149, 384); path.lineTo(469, 384); path.cubicTo(493, 384, 512, 365, 512, 341); path.lineTo(512, 43); path.cubicTo(512, 19, 493, 0, 469, 0); path.lineTo(149, 0); path.cubicTo(135, 0, 123, 7, 115, 19); path.close(); path.moveTo(192, 268); path.lineTo(222, 299); path.lineTo(299, 222); path.lineTo(375, 299); path.lineTo(405, 268); path.lineTo(329, 192); path.lineTo(405, 116); path.lineTo(375, 85); path.lineTo(299, 162); path.lineTo(222, 85); path.lineTo(192, 116); path.lineTo(268, 192); path.close();
path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);

PathShape shape = new PathShape(path, 512f, 384f);

ShapeDrawable drawable = new ShapeDrawable(shape);
drawable.setIntrinsicWidth(512);
drawable.setIntrinsicHeight(384);

ImageButton button = new ImageButton(context);
button.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
button.setImageDrawable(drawable);
button.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFAFADA);
```

Pixelated button magnified by 5:
[image: Pixelated button magnified by 5]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
Paint psPaint = drawable.getPaint();
psPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
psPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
psPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
```